# Full height layout with collapse and fixed sidebar on bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I need fixed height layout (like an application) and fixed (full height) sidebar but when resolution changed, sidebar collapse.

Example 1: (Collapse sidebar, sidebar not fixed)
 - http://www.bootply.com/render/88026

Example 2: (Full height)
 - http://www.bootply.com/render/96937

How can I implement collapse sidebar (Example 1) to full height layout (Example2)

## update 1

I try this: http://startbootstrap.com/simple-sidebar but sidebar fixed height not working on mobile browsers
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck, there's already an implementation available that solves your problem: http://startbootstrap.com/simple-sidebar

Here's a preview:
[image]

Also, when the resolution goes down, the sidebar collapses as a button.

Also, you might want to disable user-scalability in case you're facing issues by using the following tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640px, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=.5" />
```

Comment: @oguzh4n strange! It used to work. Are you sure you edited the template correctly? Post a fiddle.

Comment: Yep! Tried it again. It does work. You probably made a mistake in editing.

Comment: zoom out after load page (android browser)

Comment: It still works on my phone. How's it not working on yours? Strange!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47573/discussion-between-oguzh4n-and-ranveer)